# SQL Server creating external data source

Tags: sql, sql-server, polybase

I'm trying to create external data source in SQL Server 2019. From one SQL Server instance to another.

I have done everything like in documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).
To create external data source i use following command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE SQLServerInstance
    WITH ( LOCATION = 'sqlserver://SQL2:port',
    PUSHDOWN = ON,
    CREDENTIAL = MyCredentials);
```

But i keep getting following error:

> Msg 46721, Level 20, State 1, Line 1
>   Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the DDL from a local Windows account (i.e., non-domain joined machine)? There is a regression in SQL Server 2019 where you will get this error when trying to use PolyBase. We are in the process of fixing the issue in an upcoming CU.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue also, trying to use Polybase and ODBC to read text CSV file. I have tried with both domain user account and SQL Server sa account, continually receive same Login Failed error on a SQL Server in a domain (member of an AG cluster in fact). Server is SQL 2019 enterprise CU14 - should this be fixed by now?